# How to have elements flow in columns by height of parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Question:** How can I layout items in columns where they will fill up the column and then wrap.

Live code:
https://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/NWxqXVv

```css
.column-wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
}
.column-element {
  padding: 12px;
}
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  color: #cacaca;
  opacity: .75;
  font-size: 12px;
}
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-wrapper">
  <div class="column-element">
    <h1>Collaborators</h1>
    <p>Joe</p>
    <p>Karen</p>
    <p>Randy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-element">
    <h1>Company</h1>
    <p>R/GA</p>
    <p>Uber</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-element">
    <h1>Technology</h1>
    <p>React</p>
    <p>FusionJS</p>
    <p>Styletron</p>
    <p>Baseweb</p>
    <p>Webpack</p>
    <p>Cloudinary</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-element">
    <h1>Profession</h1>
    <p>Software Engineer</p>
    <p>Designer</p>
    <p>HR</p>
    <p>CEO</p>
    <p>CTO</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-element">
    <h1>Dates</h1>
    <p>June 3 2018 ~ Aug 28 2018</p>
  </div>
    <div class="column-element">
    <h1>My Role</h1>
    <p>Software Engineer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Desired Layout:**

[image]

Note: If `'.column-element'` inner `<p />` or `<h1 />`  were to break to the next column I'd like them to go to the next column. Therefore, using `column-count` will not work.
[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you want. I don't see the issue of the below answer. If you are fixing the height then flex-wrap with column is what you need and of course you will have an overflow on the width if you the height is fixed

Comment: He updated it! it works as intended now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following change in your `CSS` property:

```
.column-wrapper {
    height: 250px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```css
.column-wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.column-element {
  padding: 12px;
}
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  color: #cacaca;
  opacity: .75;
  font-size: 12px;
}
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-wrapper">
  <div class="column-element">
    <h1>Collaborators</h1>
    <p>Joe</p>
    <p>Karen</p>
    <p>Randy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-element">
    <h1>Company</h1>
    <p>R/GA</p>
    <p>Uber</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-element">
    <h1>Technology</h1>
    <p>React</p>
    <p>FusionJS</p>
    <p>Styletron</p>
    <p>Baseweb</p>
    <p>Webpack</p>
    <p>Cloudinary</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-element">
    <h1>Profession</h1>
    <p>Software Engineer</p>
    <p>Designer</p>
    <p>HR</p>
    <p>CEO</p>
    <p>CTO</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-element">
    <h1>Dates</h1>
    <p>June 3 2018 ~ Aug 28 2018</p>
  </div>
    <div class="column-element">
    <h1>My Role</h1>
    <p>Software Engineer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatly this will make items overflow out of the box.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood I update my ans it's working. Now `column-element` will follow `parent` `height`.